# Update existing pdf with C#

Tags: c#

I have an existing pdf file which needs to be updated with information which varies with each client. There are around 50 clients. I have to update the pdf with these. How can I acheive the same in C#. The pdf has to be shown in the browser (only IE) Is there a third party dll which could be used, which would parse the pdf. Then write to the pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd party libraries for editing include PDFSharp and iTextSharp.

Answer (score 0):

We use TallPDF for generating all our PDFs.
we have more than a hundret different PDFs which are filled with customer data coming from our DB:

http://www.tallcomponents.com/products.aspx